# Blank response in PHP using FCM for push notification to mobile app. Local it is working fine, on Centos server it is returning blank response

Tags: php, android, centos, firebase-cloud-messaging

getting blank response on Centos server and local it is working fine. I tried to disable the firewall on centos also and try again but still getting blank response.

```
$api_key = 'api_key';
$fields = array (
'registration_ids' => array (
$device_id
),
'data' => array (
"message" => $message
)
);
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization:key='.$api_key
);
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: When you say "blank response" do you mean that `$result` is empty after curl_ecec? have you tried calling `curl_error()` after the failed attempt?

Comment: Jerry - Yes, $result is empty and http status response is 200 on Centos linux server. I tried to add curl_error as suggest. but that it is also empty.      $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
print("error_msg".$error_msg);

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this error by executing below command. Most of the time we face if SELinux is enabled on our server. The curl request is blocked by SELinux.
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

after that restart your server.

sudo systemctl restart httpd